# Save gtk Pixbuf as a jpg

Tags: python, pygtk

I have a `Pixbuf` object `pb`.

If I try to save as a `jpg` I get an error:

```
pb = pb.get_from_drawable(w, w.get_colormap(), 0, 0, 0, 0, sz[0], sz[1])
pb.save("screenshot.jpg", "jpg")
```

The error I get is:

```
glib.GError: image not supported
```

If I try to save as a `png` it works:

```
pb = pb.get_from_drawable(w, w.get_colormap(), 0, 0, 0, 0, sz[0], sz[1])
pb.save("screenshot.png", "png")
```

How can I save the image in `jpg` ?

Comment: What type of object is `pb`? What is the exact error you get?

Comment: it is a gtk.gdk.Pixbuf object. I get this error: "glib.GError: image not supported"

Comment: The documentation for [**`Pixbuf.save`**](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-File-saving.html#gdk-pixbuf-save) says `"jpeg"` not `"jpg"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [**`Pixbuf.save`**](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-File-saving.html#gdk-pixbuf-save) says supported format types include `"jpeg"` not `"jpg"`:

```
pb.save("screenshot.jpg", "jpeg")
```